# NPM install error? Vulnerabilities found

Tags: npm, npm-install

Recently, I have been getting this error and do not know how to fix. I never gotten this error before.

```
npm install
```

output:

42 vulnerabilities found

I tried using npm audit and ran the npm update _____, but it didn't resolve vulnerabilities. What causing this and how do i fix?

Comment: I just received this error, too.  Maybe some malicious code is being injected into repositories, and NPM picks it up--definitely not my virus protection software though.  What happens if you uninstall nodejs and npm, reinstall, and delete the node_modules folder in your project?  I'm trying that now.

Answer (score 1):

you can fix this by running command `npm audit fix` this will try to fix all issues (mostly by updating packages).

the problem is that `npm update` only updates some minor versions (and package.lock.json) so if issue is fixed in major version than `npm update` wont fix this. you can use [npm-check](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check) to quickly update all your dependencies.